# MSSQL: How can I find records with a date field in a time range of 24 hours always starting from 6am to 6am next day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What i want to do is:
If i select a record from the date `2016-06-01 06:00:00` to `2016-06-02 05:59:59` it should display under `2016-06-01` and not under `02`

Comment: post your efforts to find the same , try with query select record where date between 2016-06-01 06:00:00 and  2016-06-02 05:59:59

Comment: You're probably looking for something like `DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(HOUR, '1900-01-01 06:00:00.000', myDate) / 24)` (possibly with grouping by `DATEDIFF(HOUR, '1900-01-01 06:00:00.000', myDate) / 24`)

Comment: If you're seeking to avoid records that occur *during* the 59th second, your endpoint is correct. Otherwise, I'd strongly suggest computing an *exclusive* endpoint (`2016-06-02T06:00:00`) and using `<` rather than `<=` or `between`. Exclusive endpoints tend to be easier to calculate and don't depend on the precision of your datetime data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is i want to do. The records after 00:00:00 to 06:00:00 should comes under '2016-06-01 06:00:00' if there is a records for the date from 2016-06-01 06:00:00 to 2016-06-02 06:00:00

CASE 
WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, RechargeOn) < DATEADD(HOUR, 6, RechargeOn)
DATEADD(HOUR, 18, DATEADD(DAY, -1, RechargeOn))
RechargeOn
END

Answer (score 0):

...`GROUP BY CAST((DATEADD(hour, -6, YourDate) AS DATE)`

if you want to find records occurring in '2016-08-05' (according to your requirement you do

```
CAST((DATEADD(hour, -6, YourDate) AS DATE) = 2016-08-05'
```

note that in my method 06:00:00 then acts like 'midnight' in a regular day system - i.e. at the stroke of 6, it is a new day

Answer (score 0):

Simply subtract six hours:

```
select dateadd(hour, -6, mydate)
from mytable
```